# Getting Heroku "Something went wrong" error message but logs seem fine?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I just deployed this app: https://knowledgesimplified.herokuapp.com/ to Heroku and keep getting this error:

We're sorry, but something went wrong.

when I try to add a book. I checked the logs per the other suggestions on stackoverflow and they don't seem to reveal anything weird happening during the GET and POST methods? (Tested it a few times during the bottom)

Any ideas here?

```
2016-03-13T20:26:11.281861+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate` by jacobjzhang@gmail.com
2016-03-13T20:26:13.624286+00:00 heroku[run.7612]: Awaiting client
2016-03-13T20:26:13.644529+00:00 heroku[run.7612]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate`
2016-03-13T20:26:13.973016+00:00 heroku[run.7612]: State changed from starting to up
2016-03-13T20:26:18.569481+00:00 heroku[run.7612]: State changed from up to complete
2016-03-13T20:26:18.583978+00:00 heroku[run.7612]: Process exited with status 0
2016-03-13T20:26:36.169580+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Restarting
2016-03-13T20:26:36.174819+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2016-03-13T20:26:38.437633+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 57338 -e production`
2016-03-13T20:26:39.436926+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2016-03-13T20:26:40.324501+00:00 app[web.1]: [2016-03-13 20:26:40] FATAL SignalException: SIGTERM
2016-03-13T20:26:40.324536+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/server.rb:174:in `select'
2016-03-13T20:26:40.324538+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/server.rb:174:in `block in start'
2016-03-13T20:26:40.324539+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/server.rb:32:in `start'
2016-03-13T20:26:40.324540+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/server.rb:162:in `start'
2016-03-13T20:26:40.324540+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:34:in `run'
2016-03-13T20:26:40.324541+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:286:in `start'
2016-03-13T20:26:40.324542+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:80:in `start'
2016-03-13T20:26:40.324543+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:80:in `block in server'
2016-03-13T20:26:40.324543+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
2016-03-13T20:26:40.324544+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
2016-03-13T20:26:40.324545+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
2016-03-13T20:26:40.324545+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
2016-03-13T20:26:40.324546+00:00 app[web.1]:    bin/rails:4:in `require'
2016-03-13T20:26:40.324547+00:00 app[web.1]:    bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
2016-03-13T20:26:40.324619+00:00 app[web.1]: [2016-03-13 20:26:40] INFO  going to shutdown ...
2016-03-13T20:26:40.324668+00:00 app[web.1]: [2016-03-13 20:26:40] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start done.
2016-03-13T20:26:40.357618+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
2016-03-13T20:26:40.357634+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 4.2.4 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:39858
2016-03-13T20:26:40.357635+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
2016-03-13T20:26:40.357636+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2016-03-13T20:26:40.357637+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2016-03-13T20:26:41.161392+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2016-03-13T20:26:41.852881+00:00 app[web.1]: [2016-03-13 20:26:41] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
2016-03-13T20:26:41.852894+00:00 app[web.1]: [2016-03-13 20:26:41] INFO  ruby 2.2.4 (2015-12-16) [x86_64-linux]
2016-03-13T20:26:41.853130+00:00 app[web.1]: [2016-03-13 20:26:41] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=3 port=57338
2016-03-13T20:26:42.216298+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2016-03-13T20:26:43.644932+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/books" host=knowledgesimplified.herokuapp.com request_id=8b5c9e1a-4f8b-4244-9961-65922856638f fwd="72.229.233.102" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=114ms status=500 bytes=1754
2016-03-13T20:26:43.909513+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=knowledgesimplified.herokuapp.com request_id=48487e1e-c89c-41a9-85aa-af1fa1056f35 fwd="72.229.233.102" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=5ms status=200 bytes=228
2016-03-13T20:26:45.824055+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/books" host=knowledgesimplified.herokuapp.com request_id=73e14298-579d-4626-976a-6bc4fa06f8e6 fwd="72.229.233.102" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=56ms status=500 bytes=1754
2016-03-13T20:26:46.050943+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=knowledgesimplified.herokuapp.com request_id=3e9c171e-2c80-40bf-b6f5-2982bfe152e8 fwd="72.229.233.102" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=3ms status=200 bytes=228
2016-03-13T20:26:50.154609+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=knowledgesimplified.herokuapp.com request_id=2b5a5cdf-cc1e-46ad-af69-44a92d7edb6f fwd="72.229.233.102" dyno=web.1 connect=6ms service=19ms status=200 bytes=2421
2016-03-13T20:26:50.294207+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/application-711137ccc0687049b1ca7564b8305e4a8ccf434944ee25bdd4bcd5953a034e2e.css" host=knowledgesimplified.herokuapp.com request_id=3540f7f3-df2b-4f10-aca7-c3f85c6a27bf fwd="72.229.233.102" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=5ms status=304 bytes=133
2016-03-13T20:26:50.353490+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/application-5cd717704717da957b340b754fd809f5c9df72c23fc096d57d63b630ffb0b4a8.js" host=knowledgesimplified.herokuapp.com request_id=d526693d-800c-4926-b999-a228f6f205c7 fwd="72.229.233.102" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=5ms status=304 bytes=133
2016-03-13T20:26:51.726377+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=knowledgesimplified.herokuapp.com request_id=882ab98c-e645-4abe-af6f-8520f88e086e fwd="72.229.233.102" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=12ms status=200 bytes=2421
2016-03-13T20:26:51.836329+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/application-711137ccc0687049b1ca7564b8305e4a8ccf434944ee25bdd4bcd5953a034e2e.css" host=knowledgesimplified.herokuapp.com request_id=f5432cac-081d-4759-9ccb-d928e177fd90 fwd="72.229.233.102" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=4ms status=304 bytes=133
2016-03-13T20:26:51.850805+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/application-5cd717704717da957b340b754fd809f5c9df72c23fc096d57d63b630ffb0b4a8.js" host=knowledgesimplified.herokuapp.com request_id=b3987d1c-5089-4d8d-8982-84a8e0e6bf43 fwd="72.229.233.102" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=3ms status=304 bytes=133
2016-03-13T20:26:52.209554+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=knowledgesimplified.herokuapp.com request_id=45953b9c-b4a5-4509-bde5-5014b1037724 fwd="72.229.233.102" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=200 bytes=228
2016-03-13T20:26:53.737424+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/books/new" host=knowledgesimplified.herokuapp.com request_id=103a71a2-41ee-437f-b3e2-207f86c04aa6 fwd="72.229.233.102" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=28ms status=200 bytes=3843
2016-03-13T20:26:55.068443+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/books" host=knowledgesimplified.herokuapp.com request_id=ecc79be3-427f-49af-930e-e21cb3ef51d6 fwd="72.229.233.102" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=12ms status=500 bytes=1754
2016-03-13T20:26:59.101628+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/users/sign_out" host=knowledgesimplified.herokuapp.com request_id=63d73e05-6b96-48a7-8b4d-205597614d7d fwd="72.229.233.102" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=15ms status=302 bytes=942
2016-03-13T20:26:59.154534+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=knowledgesimplified.herokuapp.com request_id=8778ffd3-0adf-457c-bda1-6a259dabdb71 fwd="72.229.233.102" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=19ms status=200 bytes=2518
2016-03-13T20:27:00.161766+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=knowledgesimplified.herokuapp.com request_id=2e7b436e-54c1-4abf-8c36-c25445dbaf6b fwd="72.229.233.102" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=10ms status=200 bytes=2273
2016-03-13T20:27:00.273853+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/application-5cd717704717da957b340b754fd809f5c9df72c23fc096d57d63b630ffb0b4a8.js" host=knowledgesimplified.herokuapp.com request_id=8982ca7a-fb94-4834-8e9b-4ff4302d3f92 fwd="72.229.233.102" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=7ms status=304 bytes=133
2016-03-13T20:27:00.272821+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/application-711137ccc0687049b1ca7564b8305e4a8ccf434944ee25bdd4bcd5953a034e2e.css" host=knowledgesimplified.herokuapp.com request_id=5c3f0bac-4108-4503-8ae4-fac0bee0bd83 fwd="72.229.233.102" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=4ms status=304 bytes=133
2016-03-13T20:27:00.522819+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=knowledgesimplified.herokuapp.com request_id=c2eca069-4ded-4bcc-a24b-ea4d8fda811e fwd="72.229.233.102" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=3ms status=200 bytes=228
2016-03-13T20:27:01.209354+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/users/sign_up" host=knowledgesimplified.herokuapp.com request_id=c82752d0-275f-451d-83c4-fa4bf8d9e38f fwd="72.229.233.102" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=24ms status=200 bytes=3970
2016-03-13T20:27:02.635831+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/users/sign_in" host=knowledgesimplified.herokuapp.com request_id=fea1332b-e0d4-4663-89b5-cacc7f7e464a fwd="72.229.233.102" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=19ms status=200 bytes=3664
2016-03-13T20:27:07.415110+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/users/sign_in" host=knowledgesimplified.herokuapp.com request_id=00082d38-bc88-4ae1-8e7b-a31c25a8c204 fwd="72.229.233.102" dyno=web.1 connect=6ms service=176ms status=200 bytes=3884
2016-03-13T20:27:13.188104+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/users/sign_in" host=knowledgesimplified.herokuapp.com request_id=9c54ada9-4df8-4ec1-a22b-cc9917deaa6f fwd="72.229.233.102" dyno=web.1 connect=3ms service=100ms status=302 bytes=1052
2016-03-13T20:27:13.253547+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=knowledgesimplified.herokuapp.com request_id=6c817ea7-533b-4466-a274-4e6c774d094e fwd="72.229.233.102" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=21ms status=200 bytes=2677
2016-03-13T20:27:14.558794+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=knowledgesimplified.herokuapp.com request_id=b2015734-81e7-4278-861d-545eabf1af78 fwd="72.229.233.102" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=16ms status=200 bytes=2421
2016-03-13T20:27:16.239411+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/books/new" host=knowledgesimplified.herokuapp.com request_id=9c26e295-21c8-4714-aea0-cdb121b4362d fwd="72.229.233.102" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=20ms status=200 bytes=3843
2016-03-13T20:27:17.440165+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/books" host=knowledgesimplified.herokuapp.com request_id=0c70bed9-97d5-465c-829a-5e2430975b6e fwd="72.229.233.102" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=14ms status=500 bytes=1754
2016-03-13T20:30:19.281358+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=knowledgesimplified.herokuapp.com request_id=e415142a-9d4e-4d2f-979c-9ec1e15d0532 fwd="72.229.233.102" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=13ms status=200 bytes=2421
2016-03-13T20:30:20.083363+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=knowledgesimplified.herokuapp.com request_id=fa720982-5cd6-47b5-9bd0-b43a96193e10 fwd="72.229.233.102" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=4ms status=304 bytes=133
2016-03-13T20:30:24.560012+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/books/new" host=knowledgesimplified.herokuapp.com request_id=1321b844-b177-403a-b344-cd515668de29 fwd="72.229.233.102" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=20ms status=200 bytes=3843
2016-03-13T20:30:30.066091+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/books" host=knowledgesimplified.herokuapp.com request_id=cd316acd-35cf-42f9-a77c-5a49c2c8d84e fwd="72.229.233.102" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=30ms status=500 bytes=1754
```

Answer (score 0):

Try running `heroku run rake db:migrate` in your terminal

I would also restart the heroku server and see if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered what the issue was: I did not do a migration for paperclip, which is required for the image upload. Once I ran "rails generate paperclip", it worked great. Thanks all.